# Why I can't assign the correct value to c++ enum type variable?

Tags: c++, enums, padding, memory-alignment

I can't understand what's going there.
Using Visual Studio 2008, I've defined an enum like this:

```
enum MyType{
    A,
    B,
    C
};
```

Then I use it to initialize a member variable:

```
class MyClass
{
    private:
        bool   bit_;
        uint16 num_;
        MyType member_;
    public:
        MyClass(MyType value){
            member_ = value; // This the assignment which fails
        } // Here, there's a breakpoint to query member_ value    
};
```

MyClass instance = new MyClass();

I'm using Debug configuration, so no optimization can fool me when reading
a variable. At a breakpoint just after the assignment, the debuger shows the value of member_ as `member_ = C`.

It could be a debugger whatch refresh issue but, inside a method it evaluates true when checking:

```
if(member_ == C){
    // ??
}
```

And also, assigning to the other values gives strange numbers, e.g. doing `member_ = B` gives `member_ = 258` when ferching it.
Can you tell me what's wrong? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT #1**

I've noted a funny effect which explains why after assigning `member_ = A` the expression `member_ == C` evaluates to `true` for the enum with the default values:

For the enum

```
enum MyType{ A, B, C}; // equivalent to enum MyType{ A = 0, B = 1, C = 2};
```

I get

```
MyType  a = A; // but when fetching a the value is   2  (0x0002)  thats the map for C!
MyType  b = B; // but when fetching a the value is 258  (0x0102)
MyType  c = C; // but when fetching a the value is 514  (0x0202)
```

But if I make

```
enum MyType{ A = 5, B = 6, C = 7};
```

I get

```
MyType  a = A; // but when fetching a the value is 1282  (0x0502)
MyType  b = B; // but when fetching a the value is 1538  (0x0602)
MyType  c = C; // but when fetching a the value is 1794  (0x0702)
```

So, when assigning that #?!^% enum, the rule seems to be, shift 8 bits and add 2.
It sounds like compiler issues.

Btw, making the type of `member_` to be `int` instead `MyType` doesn't changes nothing.

**EDIT #2**
Added two more members to the class, which are the real cause of the problem. I'll post the
answer as soon as the time restriction vanishes (8h from the posting of the question).

Comment: You need to show more code, what you described shouldn't happen.

Comment: If this is all your code if (var == C) will evaluate false.

Comment: VS 2008 is known for showing sometimes incorrect values in "watch windows", there should be a patch for fixing that somewhere

Comment: Try removing all temp files (.ncb, .suo, .user) and rebuilding the project.

Comment: Now this is getting really interesting after the update. You have omitted earlier many important details. Even with autonumber, if an enum entry has value of, ie 4, then even with some weird problems with endianess, the result of conversion to int16 should be either 0x0400*) or 0x0004*), but at NO circumstances would there be an additional 0x0002/0x0200 blitted into it. Aside from unions, you could also get some effect like that with a bit of playing with conversions overloads. Or, if you are dealing with **unions**. Great that you find the cause. Looking forward to see your diagnosis.

Comment: *) of course, whichever one it is, your processor would read it as 4. The difference would be visible only in raw memory view (under debug/windows/memory) (btw. check it too, it might show you if you are damaging something out-of-bounds!)

Comment: The tag `compiler` should be applied to questions concerning the programming of compilers or for questions about the detailed inner workings of compilers. Don't use `compiler` for questions about options and settings for a particular compiler, use the name of the compiler you are interested in instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone.
Somebody at work pointed me to the origin of the problem.

It's a matter of faulty configuration of the project,
which gives data alignment issues.

After compiling, with the current project settings,
the two first members of the class are 3 bytes of size.

It should be 4 bytes, hence the misalignment of 1 byte.
The extra 2 added is garbage at the misaligned byte, so, the
whole effect is to shift one byte and add 2.

This effect is cancealed adding an extra member, although
it's not an elegant solution (the solution is to configure
the project corectly).

```
class MyClass
{
    private:
        bool   bit_;  // 1 byte
        uint16 num_;  // 2 byte

        bool dummy;   // extra byte to help the alignment

        MyType member_;
    public:
        MyClass(MyType value){
            member_ = value; // Now it works as expected.
        }
};
```

Comment: Heh, one could say that `unions` backfired, but at bit lower level. However, this is still very strange, because even if you have it ill-configured and the compiler lays it out in 3 bytes, then later at the point of usage, **it should know it** and it should calculate the member offset correclty as, again, 3 bytes. It seems that not only your config is somewhat broken, double-check your way you do the config. For alignment issues, there's `#pragma pack` directive that you put in header files along with the class/struct, so that anything that pulls the header knows what align this struct uses

Comment: ..unless you #ifdef them heavily and then set the #defines differenty on different cpp/h/lib files.. As you say about configuration issues, probably that was the case?

Comment: I'll check the config, but I will not be able to change it (because works for everyone except me). It's a project which started heavily based in Windows API. I joined recently (from a Java environment, with little C++ experience) and was told to code keeping an eye on portability, to cover the (remote) possibility of having an OS change within next years. The result is that I'm the only one that uses `bool` and `uint16_t`instead `BOOL` and `DWORD`; and problems like this arise.

Answer (score 1):

Enum entries does not have to have unique values. You might have an enum with A,B,C where both A and C are equal to '42'. In such case, when the var has value of 42, the IDE **will show you only one** of the matching entries, A or C, not both.

You can easily create an enum with 'duplicate' entries, like this:

```
enum { A=1, B=1, C=1 }
```

But most probably, you didn't do it like that. However, when using autonumbering, you can accidentally (or intentionally) create duplicates too:

```
enum { A, B, C }       // 0,1,2
enum { A, B, C=0 }     // 0,1,0
enum { A=2, B=1, C }   // 2,1,2
enum { A=-1, B, C=0 }  // -1,0,0
```

Be sure to double-check your enum definition.

see i.e. http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/45-enumerated-types/